# Can I serve a HTML response from a POST using the ASP.NET Web API framework?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a very basic form on my page:

```
        <form action="api/file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

I successfully submit my `file` in order to upload it on my server. My server respond by returning some json content:

[image]

The content is as below:

```
[{"name":"Untitled.png","path":"http://localhost/uploads/Untitled.png","size":10}]
```

**My question:** how can I intercept this response from my server and display it on my page? Do I have to post my form with AJAX to have the opportunity to catch the response?

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        data: WHAT_HERE?, 
        url:"api/file",
      success: function(data){
          $("#post").html(data);
      },
       error: function(){
          $("#post").html('An error occurred.');
      }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would need to use a server-side language to handle the form submission (e.g. PHP, Java) which would call your upload script, grab the response & redirect the user to a formatted page.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment quite well. I already code server side part to receive the request (of uploading the file). This is Web API Controller (Microsoft) and this server respond with json. Now I would like my client side to retrieve this response and display it.

Comment: your server is sending back `data` I suppose you are sending something interpretted by the browser as a downloadable content, so it opens the download dialog box. Try to send back a simple string and display it in `$("#post")`

Comment: From reading your question intially, it wasn't clear that "api/file" was .NET — this is what is doing your form handling, so however your controller is set up as part of this framework is what will allow you to send a formatted response. By the time it reaches the client-side, it's too late (for non-JS). Your question is really — *'Can I serve a HTML response from a POST using the ASP.NET Web API framework?'*

Comment: Your are right, I edit my question to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with response content type. 
We had similar problem and it was solved by adding content-type to application-json on response.

Of course, we did this in MVC2 and 3, probably had to be done in MVC4, but never tried on WebAPI.
If I manage to find how it is done on WebAPI, I will edit my answer.